# $(\log_{b-2}1849)^{a-2} + (\log_{b+2}1849)^{a-2} = a$

Tags: logarithms

Prove that there are at least two positive integers $a$ for which there is a positive integer $b$ such that

$$(\log_{b-2}1849)^{a-2} + (\log_{b+2}1849)^{a-2} = a.$$

My initial approach was using the property $(\log x)^a = a\log x$.
Then changing the base rule: $$\log_a x = \frac{\ln x}{\ln a}.$$

I don't even know if my approach is correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $(\log x)^a = a\log x$ is wrong. $\log x^a = a\log x$ is right.

Answer (score 1):

Comment:Does this idea help you?

We use this relation:

$\log_b a+\log_c a=\frac1{\log _a b}+\frac1{\log _a c}=\frac{\log_a bc}{\big(\log_ab\big)\big(\log_ac\big)}$

So we may write:

$$\frac{\log_{1849} (b^2-4)}{\big(\log_{1849} (b-2)\big)\big(\log_{1849} (b+2)\big)}=a^{1/a}\times a^2$$

Comment: Note that $\log_x(y)=\frac{\log(y)}{\log(x)}$, where $\log$ is a logaritmhus of an arbitrary basis.
So $LHS=\log(a) \left(\frac 1{\log(b)}+\frac 1 {\log(c)}\right)$, but $RHS=\frac 1{\log(b)}+\frac 1 {\log(c)}$. So your "relation" is invalid.

Comment: @miracle 173 .Your comment is not valid. see edit.

Comment: sorry, you are right. I missed a log(a) factor on the RHS